# Can the evaporated mercury from an LCD harm me?

Tags: dosage, poison, mercury

I opened a laptop today and I accidentally touched on a don't touch ribbon with my screwdriver. I searched on the internet and I might have broken the screen's backlight and leaked mercury vapor (elemental). The screen still works and the light probably didn't break but assuming the worst case scenario, could a bit of vaporized mercury harm me? I opened the window for 30min. I couldn't do more because I had to work in that room.